# How to convert Selenium By object to a CSS selector?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, browser-automation

It is very common to locate objects using `By` in selenium webdriver. I am currently using a `ByChained` selector and I am wondering is there a way to convert a `By` object to a CSS selector? For example:

```
By selector = By.id('something');
String cssSelector = selector.toCSSselector();
// now cssSelector = "#something"
```

Comment: what you trying to achieve can be done using monkeypatching, however I am not sure if it's possible in java or not. In python it's easy. However if you can just create a different class with method that returns the CSS selector from id or xpath. won't that work ?

Comment: It will, but there would be also more complex cases, like ByChained etc. which are not that easy to write

Comment: When using `ByChained`, the documentation makes it look like you can use different selectors. So my question is, why do you need to convert from one `By` to the other? Something like `ByChained(By.id("someId"),By.cssSelector("#some .cssSelector"))`

Comment: `ByChained` means just to take the first `By`, then on its children find the next, and so on. I need the CSS selector from a `By` because I am writing an application that puts proxy between selenium and my testing app and injects js that listens for specific events (which I need the CSS selector for - so that I can detect the event), and thus records test cases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to convert one locator type to another locator type through code.

You can write any locator (except some XPath, e.g. containing text) as a CSS selector. Just write them all as CSS selectors and that should solve your problem. For example, your id can be located using the CSS selector, "#something". If you need an `OR`, just add a comma to the CSS selector, e.g. "#someId, #some .cssSelector" is the example from mrfreester's comment. If you have to use XPath for contained text, there is a way to specify `OR`there also.

Comment: "You can write any locator (except some XPath, e.g. containing text) as a CSS selector." this is exactly the reason why I thought I can convert By objects to css selectors. The thing is, I have to create a recorded in JS for an already existing app, which already has used different `By` objects, not just `By.cssSelector`

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but it works (in most cases). So if you really need to, you can go with something like this:

```
    public String convertToCssSelectorString(By by) {
        String byString = by.toString();
        if (byString.startsWith("By.id: ")) {
            return "#" + byString.replaceFirst("By\\.id: ", "");
        } else if (byString.startsWith("By.className: ")) {
            return "." + byString.replaceFirst("By\\.className: ", "");
        } else if (byString.startsWith("By.cssSelector: ")) {
            return byString.replaceFirst("By\\.cssSelector: ", "");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported selector type: " + byString);
        }
    }
```

It does not cover all possible selector types but you can add them in the same way. Except for xpath selector, I don't think it would be possible.